# All factors of a given number

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math

For example, I have 4800 and I would like to see all the factors of this number.

```
 # num = the number you want factors of

 def factors_of(num)
    (1..num).collect { |n| [n, num/n] if ((num/n) * n) == num}.compact
 end
```

> divisors_of(4800)
>   => [[1, 4800], [2, 2400], [3, 1600], [4, 1200], [5, 960], [6, 800], [8, 600], [10, 480], [12, 400], [15, 320], [16, 300], [20, 240], [24, 200], [25, 192], [30, 160], [32, 150], [40, 120], [48, 100], [50, 96], [60, 80], [64, 75], [75, 64], [80, 60], [96, 50], [100, 48], [120, 40], [150, 32], [160, 30], [192, 25], [200, 24], [240, 20], [300, 16], [320, 15], [400, 12], [480, 10], [600, 8], [800, 6], [960, 5], [1200, 4], [1600, 3], [2400, 2], [4800, 1]]
>
> > 

How would you do this in ruby or any language?

Comment: Wrong terminology. What you are looking for are *factors*

Comment: ok, yeah it's factors not integers.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: No, he's looking specifically for *divisors*. Although it is probably true that the best way to solve this problem is to find the *factors* (first), and the generate *divisors* from factors (second).

Comment: what's the difference between a factor and divisor?

Comment: A factor is a prime factor, a divisor is something that evenly divides a number (the divisors are all products of 0 or more factors).

Comment: @Beta, @AndreyT, @Vatine: I've never heard of the convention that "factors" means "prime factors"; it's always synonymous with "divisors". Can you give a citation for this convention? (If it were so, why would we need the adjective "prime"?)

Comment: It's the difference between American English (factors means prime factors) and British English (factors means divisors).

Comment: For context, I'm an American who studied math at an American college. In my experience, I would expect someone to say "prime factors" if that is what they meant. Factors are not necessarily prime, regardless of British/American English.

Comment: Here is a calculator that finds all the factors of a number, with detailed steps https://mathpi.net/calculators/arithmetic/factor

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In Ruby, the `prime` library gives you the factorization:

```
require 'prime'
4800.prime_division #=> [[2, 6], [3, 1], [5, 2]]
```

To get that list of yours, you take the cartesian product of the possible powers:

```
require 'prime'
def factors_of(number)
  primes, powers = number.prime_division.transpose
  exponents = powers.map{|i| (0..i).to_a}
  divisors = exponents.shift.product(*exponents).map do |powers|
    primes.zip(powers).map{|prime, power| prime ** power}.inject(:*)
  end
  divisors.sort.map{|div| [div, number / div]}
end

p factors_of(4800) # => [[1, 4800], [2, 2400], ..., [4800, 1]]
```

*Note*: In Ruby 1.8.7, you must `require 'mathn'` instead of `require 'prime'`. In Ruby 1.8.6, `require 'backports/1.8.7/enumerable/inject'` or modify the `inject` above...

Comment: Great. This sort of solution — e.g. for number=12, doing (2^0, 2^1, 2^2) x (3^0, 3^1) — is *much* faster for large (esp. composite) numbers than the code in the question. Ruby looks cool!

Comment: Can someone explain the *factors_of* in a math way?

Comment: The prime factorization shows the combination of primes that when multiplied together, equal the number. However, dividing by any of those primes yields a number with a similar prime factorization sans the one divided. So e.g. pf(4800) = 2^6*3*5^2. Divide by 2, and you have pf(2400) = 2^5*3*5^2, by 2 again pf(1200) = 2^4*3*5^2. This iterates all possible combinations.

Answer (score 29):

```
 def divisors_of(num)
   (1..num).select { |n|num % n == 0}
 end
```

Comment: and `1...num` for proper divisors

Answer (score 7):

I think [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factors_of_an_integer#Ruby) solution is nicer, especially because it doesn't perform so many loops, it doesn't require the Prime library and most importantly it runs til `Math.sqrt(n)`.
Here's the code:

```
class Integer
  def factors
    1.upto(Math.sqrt(self)).select {|i| (self % i).zero?}.inject([]) do |f, i| 
      f << i
      f << self / i unless i == self / i
      f
  end.sort
end

# Usage
4800.factors
```

If you want to **pair them up**, just like in your example, you can use the following piece of code (which pairs up first with last and in case there's an odd number of factors, then the middle one is the square root):

```
class Integer
  def paired_up_factors
    a = self.factors
    l = a.length
    if l % 2 == 0
      a[0, l / 2].zip(a[- l / 2, l / 2].reverse)
    else
      a[0, l / 2].zip(a[- l / 2 + 1, l / 2].reverse) + [a[l / 2], a[l / 2]]
    end
  end
end

# Usage
4800.paired_up_factors
```

Comment: You have a bug.
`irb(main):026:0> 64.paired_up_factors
=> [[1, 64], [2, 32], [4, 16], 8, 8]`

last set should be [8,8]

Comment: Does wrapping that last summand (`[a[l / 2], a[l / 2]]`) in another `[` pair `]` help?

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't come with batteries to do the factorisation, but starting with

```
>>> p=[[2, 6], [3, 1], [5, 2]]

>>> from itertools import product
>>> print sorted(reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,j) for j in product(*[[x**i for i in range(0,y+1)] for x,y in p]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 20, 24, 25, 30, 32, 40, 48, 50, 60, 64, 75, 80, 96, 100, 120, 150, 160, 192, 200, 240, 300, 320, 400, 480, 600, 800, 960, 1200, 1600, 2400, 4800]
```

Comment: The question is about Ruby. Not python.

Comment: @Mohamad, What does "or any language" mean to you then?

Comment: Fair enough, but the question should be tagged language agnostic, not Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do an O(sqrt(n)) algorithm that does not need prime factorization. If you see at your list, for every pair [a, b] in your list such that `a <= b`, the pair [b, a] also appears. This allows you to iterate only up to `sqrt(n)`, because `a <= sqrt(n)`.

To prove that for every pair [a, b] such that `a <= b` it holds that `a <= sqrt(n)` you can use a proof by contradiction. Let's assume that `a > sqrt(n)`. If `a > sqrt(n)`, then `b > sqrt(n)` too, because `b >= a`. Therefore:

`a * b > sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) = n`

which contradicts the fact that `a * b == n`. So the following the algorithm will generate all pairs (the following code is in C++):

```
void GeneratePairs(int n) {
  for (int a = 1; a <= n / a; ++a)
    if (n % a == 0) {
      const int b = n / a;
      printf("[%d, %d] ", a, b);
      if (a != b)  // be careful with square numbers
        printf("[%d, %d] ", b, a);
    }
  printf("\n");
}
```

The only issue is that this code does not generate the pairs in order. One solution is to store them in a vector, sort them and then print them, or doing two passes, one forward and one backwards:

```
void GeneratePairsTwoPasses(int n) {
  const int sq = static_cast<int>(sqrt(n));
  for (int a = 1; a <= sq; ++a)
    if (n % a == 0)
      printf("[%d, %d] ", a, n / a);
  for (int a = sq - 1; a >= 1; --a)
    if (n % a == 0)
      printf("[%d, %d] ", n / a, a);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question doesn't really ask about the results of the divisions, and you can call product by converting array of arrays to array parameters.

```
n= 4800
pd= n.prime_division.map{ |pd| (0..pd[1]).map{ |i| pd[0]** i } }
p (pd.length== 1 ? pd[0] : pd[0].product(*pd.drop(1)).map{ |a, b| a* b })[0..-2].uniq
```

Comment: [I also took the liberty of removing n from the list of divisors.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperDivisor.html)

Comment: I think your answer would be clearer if you hadn't removed `1` and `n`. After all the number is prime if and only if the array returned contains just two elements. Also, do you need `uniq`?

Answer (score 2):

Using brute force, you can skip half of the numbers, since for `n`, numbers greater than `n / 2` obviously can't be divisors, so to speed up calculation, you can go from `n` to `n / 2` and then just add `n` itself. I've also added `.uniq` for `n = 1` case:

```
((1..(n / 2.0).ceil).select { |i| n % i == 0 } + [n]).uniq
```

Comment: Actually, the cap is `Math.sqrt(n)`, not `n / 2.0`

Comment: A simple proof : Let `x = Math.sqrt(num).to_i`. We wish to show that for  every factor `n` of `num` for which `n > x`, the corresponding factor, `num/n`, is less than `x`. That follows because `num/n = x*num/x*n < x*num/x*x =  x*num/x*x = x*num/num = x`. We may there compute each factor `f` up to `num**0.5` and add the corresponding factor `num/f`.

Answer (score 2):

This is Ruby code.

```
require 'prime'

def divisors(n)
  arr = Prime.prime_division(n).map { |v,exp| (0..exp).map { |i| v**i } }
  arr.first.product(*arr[1..-1]).map { |a| a.reduce(:*) }.map { |m| [m,n/m] }
end
```

For example,

```
divisors 24
  #=> [[1, 24], [3, 8], [2, 12], [6, 4], [4, 6], [12, 2], [8, 3], [24, 1]] 
divisors 9
  #=> [[1, 9], [3, 3], [9, 1]] 
divisors 450
  #=> [[1, 450], [5, 90], [25, 18], [3, 150], [15, 30], [75, 6], [9, 50],
  #    [45, 10], [225, 2], [2, 225], [10, 45], [50, 9], [6, 75], [30, 15],
  #    [150, 3], [18, 25], [90, 5], [450, 1]]
```

For n = 24, the steps are as follows:

```
a   = Prime.prime_division(n)
  #=> [[2, 3], [3, 1]] 
arr = a.map { |v,exp| (0..exp).map { |i| v**i } }
  #=> [[1, 2, 4, 8], [1, 3]] 
b   = arr.shift
  #=> [1, 2, 4, 8] 
arr
  #=> [[1, 3]] 
c   = b.product(*arr)
  #=> [[1, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [4, 1], [4, 3], [8, 1], [8, 3]] 
d   = c.map { |a| a.reduce(:*) }
  #=> [1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 12, 8, 24]
```

Lastly,

```
d.map { |m| [m,n/m] }
```

returns the array given above.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, any of these two:

```
import Control.Monad

factorsOf :: (Integral a) => a -> [(a,a)]
factorsOf n = [(x,n `div` x) | x <- [1..n], n `mod` x == 0]

factorsOf_ :: (Integral a) => a -> [(a,a)]
factorsOf_ n = do
    x <- [1..n]
    guard (n `mod` x == 0)
    return (x, n `div` x)
```

Comment: This does trial division by every integer up to n, which is extremely inefficient for large n.

Comment: Yep. You should definetely not use this code if performance is an issue. :)

Comment: The OP is asking for Ruby. How does Haskell help him?

Answer (score 1):

In F#:

```
let factors n = [for i in 1..n do if n%i=0 then yield i]
```

Other language implementations can be found [here at Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Factors_of_an_integer).

Comment: The question asks "How would you do this in ruby or any language?"

Answer (score 1):

```
def divisors(n)
  divisors = []    # Initialize an empty array where we store our divisors
  for i in 1..n
    divisors.push([i,n-i]) if n % i == 0    # Only pushes if i is a divisor of n
  end
  divisors      # returns our array
end
```