# Quickest way to find factors of a given number

Tags: ruby, performance, loops

If I have a function `factors_of(number)`, and I'm looking for the fastest way to find all of the factors of that number.

The fastest I have tried so far is

```
def factors_of(number)
  factors = 0
  n = 1
  while n <= number
    if number % n == 0
      factors += 1
    end
    n += 1
  end
  factors
end
```

but it gets sluggish as the numbers get larger. Do I need to iterate over n every time from `n..number` or is there a shortcut?

Comment: See this answer to annother question asking about factorization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3398195/3057752

Comment: Are you looking for the factors or the number of factors? Your question title and your question text say the former but your code computes the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me whether you are looking for the factors (as the question title and question text say) or the number of distinct factors (which is what your code seems to compute). Depending on what *exactly* you mean, one of these might give you the answer you want:

```
require 'prime'

# prime factors
def factors_of(number)
  number.prime_division.map(&:first)
end

factors_of(12)
# => [2, 3]

# number of prime factors
def factors_of(number)
  number.prime_division.map(&:last).inject(:+)
end

factors_of(12)
# => 3

# number of distinct prime factors
def factors_of(number)
  number.prime_division.size
end

factors_of(12)
# => 2
```

Comment: that's an excellent, detailed example.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for all divisors (as you original code appears to), you need only search up to the square root of the number, i.e.

```
def divisors_of(number)
  divisors = []
  n = 1
  while n <= number ** 0.5
    if number.modulo(n) == 0
      divisors << n
      divisors << number / n unless number / n == n
    end
    n += 1
  end
  divisors.sort
end
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do this by first finding all the prime factors, but this algorithm is pretty easy to understand, and it at least cuts the complexity down to O(sqrt(n)) rather than O(n).