# how to find all factors of a given number N with time complexity less then N?

Tags: c++, factors

i am trying this but on input>10000 this loop id taking much more time.

is there is any way to optimize this which has time complexity less then N or (logn)?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n = 10001;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            cout << i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use [Pollard Rho](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) Algorithm. It's really fast and not to difficult to implement. With the prime factors you could generate the divisors.

Comment: Do you need to perform this once or many times?

Comment: if user gives input 300 then i have to perform 600 times..twice

Comment: Maybe you can find it from this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398159/all-factors-of-a-given-number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398159/all-factors-of-a-given-number)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [dmh2000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25061617/577603): You can exploit redundancies in the checking. For example, if a number is not divisible by `n` it is also not divisible by any multiple of `n`. For example a number that is not divisible by 2 also cannot be divided by 4, 6, or 8.

This technique is known as [sieving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: rahulk wants all the factors, not just all the prime factors.

Comment: This technique does just that.

Comment: "a number that is not divisible by 2 also cannot be divided by 4, 6, or 8" its true but it will make same  time complexity because i need to check whether 4 is multiple of 2 or not.. it will be same in implementation

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate up to just the square root of n rather than n, since anything bigger than the square root can't be a factor of n. edit : read ComicSansMs answer was better than my edit

Comment: rahulk wants all the factors, not just all the prime factors.

Comment: you could only check `2` and the `odd numbers` bellow `sqrt(N)`.

Comment: @TonyK So? Suggested method let to collect all factors

Comment: Using the prime factors, the divisor could be generated fairy easily.

Comment: @ST3: Yes of course. But it bears mentioning. I suspect that dmh2000 simply misread the question (like I did at first).

Answer (score 1):

First step is to find all the prime factors, with their multiplicity. Then you can generate the factors easily.

Finding the prime factors is quite fast on average for numbers up to about 100000000, if you do it sensibly. If you find a factor, you can divide it out of `n`, which reduces the time enormously in the general case. Also you only need to check odd factors up to sqrt(n), apart from 2:

```
// I assume n is non-zero
while (!(n & 1)) {
    cout << "2" << endl;
    n /= 2;
}
for (unsigned int factor = 3; factor * factor <= n; factor += 2) {
    while (n % factor == 0) {
        cout << factor << endl;
        n /= factor;
    }
if (n != 1)
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to perform this many times, there is a good solution. I'll give just an example, implementation will be your business.

---

Lets say you need to factorize two numbers, e.g. 580 and 72.

At first you factorize it into primes

```
580 = 2 x 2 x 5 x 29
72 = 2 x 2 x 2 x 3 x 3
```

Speed of factorization into primes could be highly increased using caching. You should have `std::set<int>` which contains all know prime numbers, so after factorizing `580` it contains `2, 5, 29`. That means to factorize `72` you will only need to determine that `3` is prime.

After you have all prime factors you need to multiply them in all combinations to get non-prime factors.

---

As I mentioned this solution is really good only in case you need to factorize many numbers, but if you need to factorize only once it is just not bad [Sieving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) would be better.