# Ruby array product with asterisk

Tags: ruby, arrays

I was studying how to list out all divisors of a number and came across this solution by Marc-Andre [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398159/all-factors-of-a-given-number). In his solution, there is one part of the code which does something like this:

```
array.product(*arrays_of_array) # the asterisk seems to have done sth.
```

I tried it in irb to try play around but I couldn't make sense of the outputs. I tried:

```
a=[0,1,2]
b=[3,4]
c=[[5,6],[7,8]]
```

I understand that `array.product(other_array)` is a method to list all combinations of the two arrays into one. With this knowledge, I tested out several experiments

```
a.product(b)      => [[0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]] / 6 elements
a.product(*b)     => TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Array
a.product(c)      => [[0, [5, 6]], [0, [7, 8]], [1, [5, 6]], [1, [7, 8]], [2, [5, 6]], [2, [7, 8]]] / 6 elements
a.product(*c)     => [[0, 5, 7], [0, 5, 8], [0, 6, 7], [0, 6, 8], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 6, 7], [2, 6, 8]]
```

From observation, It seems the `asterisk (*)` has to be applied to a multi-dimensional array? (i.e. matrix?). Without the asterisk, the product returns 6 elements and the combinations only one level. While with the asterisk, the combination will go 1 level deeper and returns 12 elements, and combine until there is no array within the combinations. Where can I find more examples to study this behaviour of the asterisk?

---

**Edit:**

I tried to introduce one more variable

```
d=[[[9,0],[1,2]],[[3,4],[5,6]]]
a.product(*d) => [[0, [9, 0], [3, 4]], [0, [9, 0], [5, 6]], [0, [1, 2], [3, 4]], [0, [1, 2], [5, 6]], [1, [9, 0], [3, 4]], [1, [9, 0], [5, 6]], [1, [1, 2], [3, 4]], [1, [1, 2], [5, 6]], [2, [9, 0], [3, 4]], [2, [9, 0], [5, 6]], [2, [1, 2], [3, 4]], [2, [1, 2], [5, 6]]]
```

So the asterisk sign only makes it go one level deeper.

---

In the context of finding the list of divisors. Can anyone explain what the code exactly does?

```
require 'prime'

def factors_of(number)
    primes, powers = number.prime_division.transpose
    exponents = powers.map{|i| (0..i).to_a}
    divisors = exponents.shift.product(*exponents).map do |powers|
        primes.zip(powers).map{|prime, power| prime ** power}.inject(:*)
    end
    divisors.sort.map{|div| [div, number / div]}
end

p factors_of(4800) # => [[1, 4800], [2, 2400], ..., [4800, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*`(splat) is used to expand collections.

In your example, with `b = [3,4]`,

```
a.product(*b)
```

is equivalent to

```
a.product(3, 4)
```

which generates an error because `Array#product` expects an Array as argument, not two integers.

Comment: Thanks @yuhao would you be able to expand your solution to also use a.product(*c) as another example to illustrate how it will expand? Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: @ChrisYeung `a.product(*c)` => `a.product([5,6],[7,8]`