# Ruby Hash#select method returns incomplete hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to solve Project Euler Question #21 in Ruby.

> Let d(n) be defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less than n which divide evenly into n).
>   If d(a) = b and d(b) = a, where a ≠ b, then a and b are an amicable pair and each of a and b are called amicable numbers.
>   For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore d(220) = 284. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so d(284) = 220.
>   Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000.

I used brute-force method to find a solution which finds the sum of all divisors of each number in [2,10000) range and pushes them into a hash object.

```
require 'prime'
#Method reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398159/all-factors-of-a-given-number
def factors_of(number)
  primes, powers = number.prime_division.transpose
  exponents = powers.map{|i| (0..i).to_a}
  divisors = exponents.shift.product(*exponents).map do |powers|
    primes.zip(powers).map{|prime, power| prime ** power}.inject(:*)
  end
  #Modified line
  divisors.sort![0..divisors.size-2]
end

ht=Hash.new
(2..10000).each do |x|
  arr=factors_of(x)
  sum=arr.reduce(:+)
  ht[x]=sum
end

amicable=ht.select { |key, value|  value==ht.key(key) && ht.key(key)!=key}

puts amicable
```

Output of this code

```
{220=>284, 284=>220, 1184=>1210, 1210=>1184, 2620=>2924, 5020=>5564, 5564=>5020, 6232=>6368, 6368=>6232}
```

It finds all amicable pairs except {2924=>2620}. All other numbers have their reverse pair except {2620=>2924}, {2924=>2620}. What I am missing here? Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hash#key` only returns the first key with the given value. You could do something like

```
a = ht.select{ |k,v| ht[v] == k && k!= v}
```

and look for keys rather than value, because keys can't be duplicates and they are the only things that can be trusted.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I'll keep in mind your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

`Hash#key` returns the *first* key that has the value of the argument, like so:

```
2.2.3 :043 > h = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>2}
2.2.3 :044 > h.key(2)
 => :b
```

In your case, `ht.key(2924) == 2172` because the sum of the factors of 2172 also happens to be 2924 and 2172 < 2620.

So, no ruby bug present. As for how to fix it, that's left as an exercise for you.

Comment: I think @cozyconemotel 's solution did not allow me to try this exercise.

Comment: Fair enough. You should still go ahead and mark (either) answer as correct!