# How can I duplicate and delete from an array without changing the original one?

Tags: arrays, ruby, debugging, math

My goal is to write a method, `trickysum(n)` that does the following:

The method takes range of numbers 1 through n. The method then finds pairs of numbers in that range that meet a tricky qualification: **The product of the pair of numbers must be equal to the sum of all numbers in the range, excluding this pair.** The method then returns all number pairs that meet this qualification. Here is the expectation:

```
  trickysum(26) 
  #=>[(15, 21), (21, 15)]
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def trickysum(n)

result = []
arr = (1..n).to_a

0.upto(arr.length - 1) do |x|

  0.upto(arr.length - 1) do |y|

    prod = arr[x] * arr[y]
    #I create a new array to delete from to not affect the original 
    #array. Would also love an easier way to do this :)
    new_arr = arr  
    new_arr.delete(new_arr[x])
    new_arr.delete(new_arr[y])
    sum = new_arr.inject(:+)
    if sum == prod
      result << "(#{arr[x]},#{arr[y]})"
    end
  end
end

result 

end
```

I've looked over this code over and over and can't figure out why I'm getting the following error:

```
nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
(repl):7:in `*'
(repl):7:in `block (2 levels) in trickysum'
(repl):6:in `upto'
(repl):6:in `block in trickysum'
(repl):5:in `upto'
(repl):5:in `trickysum'
(repl):20:in `<main>'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Here's a better algorithm. Let S be the sum of 1 through n. Then you want `x*y=S-x-y`. That can be rearranged as `(x+1)*(y+1)=S+1`. So if `S` is composite, just find the proper divisor pairs of `S`.

Comment: When asking a question, we need a much better title, a "how to" do something.

Comment: @RoryDaulton How is `(31, 10)` a solution? David clearly stated "1 to **n**" in the range (and in this case, `n == 26`).

Comment: @TomLord: Yes, you are right, I messed up by forgetting a key requirement. I have deleted that comment, but my previous comment still stands if the requirement is added.

Comment: A prime factorisation approach is certainly valid, and more performant for large values of `n`. However, that would require a [totally different, much more mathematical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3398195/1954610) solution -- which is probably not what was really being asked about here.

Comment: @theTinMan I thought about it for a while, but since I didn't quite know *what* that problem was, it was hard to think of a better title. I'll try going forward, though!

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
new_arr = arr
```

With:

```
new_arr = arr.dup
```

What's happening here is that you have created a **shallow copy** of the `arr` variable. Without explicitly duplicating the value, both `new_arr` and `arr` share the same location in memory.

Because of this, when you call `new_arr.delete(new_arr[x])` and `new_arr.delete(new_arr[y])`, not only are you mutating the *new* array, but also the *old* one.

This means `arr` gets shorter in length, so your outer loop goes beyond its final value and you get a `nil`; hence the error.

---

With that said, I would have written this method totally differently, which would have avoided such subtle errors:

```
def trickysum(n)
  sum = (1..n).inject(:+)
  (1..n).combination(2).select do |a, b|
    (a * b) + a + b == sum
  end
end
```

Ruby is a *very* expressive language. If you find yourself doing looping within loops, declaring temporary variables and appending to an array of results ... Then there's probably a much more elegant solution :)

Comment: \* Note that "my solution" may not be *exactly* what you are after... Can the "pairs" of numbers be identical, or do they have to be unique? If `[4, 6]` is one solution, then is `[6, 4]` really a separate solution that you want to return? (That seems a bit unnecessary...) And lastly, I have returned an array of arrays, whereas you were returning an array of *Strings*(?!).

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful, and definitely answered my question. I am new to ruby (only a handful of months in), so I'm used to using fairly simple techniques. I follow your code, but have one question: In your block, how does (a * b) + a + b == sum check if it equals the requirements? I guess that is more of a mathematical question, however.

Comment: @DavidWebster *"The product of the pair of numbers must be equal to the sum of all numbers in the range, excluding this pair"* ... Or in other words, `a * b == sum - a - b`. Rearrange the equation, and what do you get?